# Why is this Web API 2 action returning 404 not found?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Here is my ApiController:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Campaign")]
public class CampaignController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICampaignLogic _campaignLogic;

    public CampaignController(ICampaignLogic campaignLogic)
    {
        _campaignLogic = campaignLogic;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCampaignsByYearCompanyAndContactIds/{companyId:int}/{contactId:int}/{year:int}")]
    public List<Campaign> GetCampaignsByYearCompanyAndContactIds(int companyId, int contactId, int year)
    {
        return _campaignLogic.GetByYearCompanyAndContactIds(year, companyId, contactId);
    }
}
```

And here is where I make the call in AngularJS:

```
$http.get(ApiUrl + "/api/Campaign/GetCampaignsByYearCompanyAndContactIds",
        { params: { year: $scope.year, companyId: $scope.client, contactId: $scope.contactId } })
        .then(function (responses) {

    })
```

This is what is being called when I debug it in Chrome:

```
http://localhost/MyApi/api/Campaign/GetCampaignsByYearCompanyAndContactIds?companyId=12046&contactId=13662&year=2016
```

Everything is set up correctly in terms of my localhost as I am calling other API actions without any problem. However, when I call this one I am getting a 404 Not Found error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your route the url needs to have the parameters included in the route and not a part of the query string. if you want to make them available only in the query string then remove them from the route attribute.

What you should be passing in AngularJS

```
http://localhost/MyApi/api/Campaign/GetCampaignsByYearCompanyAndContactIds/12046/13662/2016
```

So you will need to build the URL using the parameters, you cannot use `params` with this url.

If you want to use `params` in AngularJS change the `Route` attribute to the following.

```
[Route("GetCampaignsByYearCompanyAndContactIds")]
```

Comment: That was it, thank you. For future reference, if I wanted to include them in the route, would I just have to concatenate them in when I call it in Angular?

Comment: @halterdev - correct and in the same order as you define them in the route.